# Does GIL implementation became worse since Python3.2?

Tags: python, performance, gil

I have read great presentation about GIL:
http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf

And here Dave said, that since Python3.2 we have new and better version of GIL, and provide examples, that prove it (on slide 54).

But when I test them on my own on Python 3.4, the performance seems to be worse:

```
from threading import Thread

def count(n):
  while n > 0:
    n -= 1

def sequential_test():
  count(100000000)
  count(100000000)

def threaded_test():
  t1 = Thread(target=count,args=(100000000,))
  t1.start()
  t2 = Thread(target=count,args=(100000000,))
  t2.start()
  t1.join()
  t2.join()
```

So on my Linux dual core laptop 
in Python 2.7 I get:

```
sequential_test: 11s
threaded_test: 17s
```

in Python 3.4 I get:

```
sequential_test: 18s
threaded_test: 28s
```

So the question is why in Python 3.4 in both cases code works slower and why I do not see any improvement in GIL on two CPU-bound processes compare to Python2?

May be I do something wrong?

My guess is that in Python2 there is some C-code optimisation of such kind of code and that's why it works faster, but I have no proff of it

Comment: With twice as many iterations I'm seeing 2.7: 14/22 (+57%), 3.5: 22/27 (+23%). Python3 seems slower overall even on sequential, but the GIL does seem to be doing better at least in 3.5 than your numbers indicate.

Comment: would be interesting also to see with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)

Comment: Does python2's speed change by using `100000000L` as argument? Remember that in python3 all integers are longs and they are necessarily slower (which may account for a significant difference in the sequential test).  Also note that while the threaded version is still slower in python3 the relative increase in time is smaller than the one for python2, though not by a huge factor.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, I have installed Python 3.5, and get such result: `17/28(+64%)`, if use twice more data, the proportion left near the same `34/55 (+62%)`.
@Bakuriu, you are right! When I set `100000000L` in python2, I get such results: `34/47(+38%)`, so python3 perform faster.


@Bakuriu, @JoachimIsaksson As I see in each of my experiments, threaded version relative increase is higher in python3.

Comment: Both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 seem to experience almost exactly the same multiplicative factor slowdown in the multithreaded case. I don't see anything to blame the GIL changes for.

Answer (score -1):

I tested this loop:

```
    for (i=0; i<loops; i++)
    {
        Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
        Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
    }
```

With loops set to 10,000,000 on Centos 7, i7-2600

Python 2.7
real    0m0.199s
user    0m0.109s
sys     0m0.011s

Python 3.7
real    0m0.912s
user    0m0.791s
sys     0m0.009s

2.7 is nearly 8x faster (CPU time)

Comment: Hi user11585016, to get help or your question answered, you need to ask the question in clear and concise manner. You are not doing so.